# Is there a mistake in rotational temperature of HF on Wikipedia?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am referencing this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_temperature

So, I see that $\theta _R = \frac{(h/2\pi)^2}{2Ik_b}$.

I took the value of $I$ from https://cccbdb.nist.gov/mieigen2x.asp.

However, when I do the calculations for $\theta _R$ by plugging in the numbers, I get
$$\theta _R = 46.8324 K$$
not $30.2K$.
Here is my Mathematica snippet
[image]

My question is, has Wikipedia gone wrong, or am I messing this up somewhere?

Comment: Where does the value of $30.2K$ come from?

Comment: The table in wikipedia has that value @Jonas